# how to make icons with no links invisible to the user

Tags: php, html

I need help on this please. I want to show only those whose links are not empty. Meaning if there are empty links from the database, that particular list item for where there is an empty link should not show

```
<?php
foreach ($stmtsocials as $socials) { ?>
    <ul class="social-profile social-profile-styled">
         <li><a href="<?php echo $socials['LT_SOC_FB'] ?>" class="facebook-bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook"><i class="facebook-bg"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $socials['LT_SOC_TWITTER'] ?>" class="twitter-bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Twitter"><i class="lab la-twitter"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $socials['LT_SOC_IG'] ?>" class="instagram-bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Instagram"><i class="lab la-instagram"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Should be an easy `if (empty($variable))` statement.

Comment: `if (!empty($socials['LT_SOC_FB'])) {`...then output the link. That should do it. Were you stuck for any particular reason? It's not clear what you'd tried already.

Comment: Unrelated, is a `foreach` needed here? Do you have multiple fb, twitter, ig accounts you need to show?

Comment: What is value of `$socials`?

Answer (score 2):

One option is that you can do like following using if condition.

```
   <?php
        foreach ($stmtsocials as $socials) { ?>
           <ul class="social-profile social-profile-styled">
            <?php if (!empty($socials['LT_SOC_FB'])){?>
               <li><a href="<?php echo $socials['LT_SOC_FB'] ?>" class="facebook-bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Facebook"><i class="facebook-bg"></i></a></li>
            <?php }?>
           <?php if (!empty($socials['LT_SOC_TWITTER'])){?>
               <li><a href="<?php echo $socials['LT_SOC_TWITTER'] ?>" class="twitter-bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Twitter"><i class="lab la-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <?php }?>
         <?php if(!empty($socials['LT_SOC_IG'])){?>
              <li><a href="<?php echo $socials['LT_SOC_IG'] ?>" class="instagram-bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Instagram"><i class="lab la-instagram"></i></a></li>
         <?php }?>
           </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

**And 2nd option** is you can select only those rows which are not empty using query. Then you don't need for `if condtion`